# Universal Logout

Tags: users

I would like to have a universal Log out for different applications that are displayed in form of multiple tabs.

I am using Drupal 7.17.

I have a Drupal Logout, but it doesn't actually log me out from the external apps that I have displayed under the different tabs.

Is there a module I can use in Drupal that would allow to log me out from multiple applications at once in one click of a button.

Right now, if I log in one of the app, its logs me through all the apps, but when I log out from one app, it only logs me out from one app at at time.

Thank you for your help!
Izumi.

Comment: what kind of app system you are using?

Comment: @JhilkeDai Thank you for looking at it. These are custom apps built over the years. Mainly in .NET. The log off URL are either of the type **javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$alogout$lnkLogOut','')** or **https://www.domainname/web/logoff.aspx**

Comment: I am not sure if there is module for that, but I guess you can set-up some custom code to kill the session of all the apps. By default Drupal only destroys its session. I guess if you use `js` logout then you can use jquery to call those scripts, lets say when user hits logout in Drupal, make a jquery on `click` or `onChange` function that will call that `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$alogout$lnkLogOut','')`.